# HDMI on MacBook Pro stopped working

Tags: display, macbook-pro, hdmi

The HDMI port on my MacBook Pro doesn't seem to be functioning normally.

When I plug it into the TV, the screen temporarily turns black as if it is connecting to the TV, the mirror connection even comes up and I can see the other display (My Tv) and change the settings.

However, on my TV it shows a `No Signal` message. What is the reason for this? When I hook my Xbox 360 up via the same port, it works flawlessly on the TV. This leads me to believe the is a problem with my laptop. It was just working a couple of days ago, and detects the external device just fine. What is the reason for the `No Signal`/black screen issue?

Comment: try a different hdmi cable

Comment: I've tried three different cables, all of which work with my Xbox.

Answer (score 2):

1. could be a hdmi cable issue
2. maybe restart your computer. in OSX 10.9 Mavericks has some issue with dual monitoring, restart without the video cable plugged in . once its fully started, try plugging in the video cable again.

Comment: Nope, the error still persists.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your repair attempts

It is not

..the HDMI cable

..the TV

...the TV input source selector

It starts the connection to the TV but then it shows "no signal"

all this leads to the display settings on your Mac.

Somehow or something has changed those settings, so while connected look the display settings for the TV.

Also make sure your  Mac correctly identifies the TV model (Sharp, Samsung ect.) in About this Mac for example.

Additionally there is a little app on your Mac Utility folder called ColorSync Utility, use it to verify and repair the settings.

Here is a screen shot (without TV connected)

[image: colorsync]